# Mockito and final equals() method in class - is it mockable?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I want to mock a class from other library using Mockito. I read that Mockito relies on specific (CGLIB provided I think) implementation of equals method. Unfortunately this outer class has equals() denoted with final modifier, and there is throwing exception in its body.

When I try to mock this class I always get exception from this method. CGLIB apparently doesn't get by with final, and real method is called.

Any ideas? What can I do, to mock this class using Mockito? Maybe other library will handle it?

[EDIT] quick explanation: I don't want to mock equals(), I check other methods. Problem is that mockito internally uses equals(), I don't know what for. As equals() is final, real method is called with exception throwing. I had hope that there is some setting in mockito "don't use equals()" :-)
Thanks for answers, I will read them closely tomorrow.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: No, you can't mock such a class directly with Mockito.  Are you able to wrap it, when  you use it in your application, then mock the wrapper?

Comment: Yes, wrapper wold be solution, but in this case I have to use that class, or subclass so that tricky equals() will remain. Anyway, I wrote mock by hand, fortunately that class isn't final, so I've extended it.

Answer (score 6):

This matrix shows features supported by different frameworks:
[image: mock framework feature comparison]

External link to the matrix [here](http://jmockit.org/MockingToolkitComparisonMatrix.html).

According to this, only [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal) and [JMockit](http://jmockit.github.io/) can mock final methods.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito cannot mock final methods. Apparently [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal) can though.

A hacky workaround could be to create a non-final method that delegates to the final `equals` method and mock that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the steps to mock a final method with PowerMock and Mockito API would be: run your tests with the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` then prepare the class you want to mock `@PrepareForTest(ClassToBeMocked.class)`. After that, mock your object and use the `when` method to mock the `equals` method.

I think that it won't work if you do not use the `PrepareForTest` annotation in your test class.

Comment: I don't like Powermock because I associate it with mocking static method, which is evil. But in this case, its use is maybe justified. Anyway, I wrote mock by hand.